# Function with number of arguments as parameter

Tags: function-construction, argument-patterns

I would like to write a function that generates the expression
$\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_L} f(i_1,\ldots,i_L) \left(s_{i_1}\ldots s_{i_L}\right)$

where $i_j\in \left\{0,1,2,3\right\}$ and $s_{i_j}$ are string variables. The parameter to be passed to the function is the number of terms $L$. For example for L=2 one could generate it with

```
Sum[f[{j, k}] ("s" <> ToString@j <> " " <> "s" <> ToString@k), {j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}]
```

However I would like to create a function

```
g[L_]:=...
```

That generalise the previous expression for arbitrary L. Maybe this could be done by creating a list

```
variables={j1,... ,jL}
```

which could be passed to a function of variable number of arguments as

```
g[variables__]:=...
```

? Is it a better way to do it?

Comment: According to your description, the sum above should be `{j, 0, 3}, {k, 0, 3}`, right?

Comment: yes you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this kind of thing, but the least work is probably to use Array.  For example, if we define

```
sumindices[func_,numindices_Integer]:=Plus@@Flatten@Array[func,Table[2,{numindices}],0]
```

Given a generic function g, if we type

```
sumindices[g, 2]
```

we then get

```
g[0, 0] + g[0, 1] + g[1, 0] + g[1, 1]
```

To get the output you want, we then define a function to make the string

```
makestr[indices___]:= StringDrop[StringJoin@@("s"<>ToString[#]<>" "&/@{indices}),-1]
```

Then we can define

```
makef[indices___]:= f[{indices}][makestr[indices]]
```

And your desired output should be

```
sumindices[makef,2]
```

which gives

```
f[{0, 0}]["s0 s0"] + f[{0, 1}]["s0 s1"] + f[{1, 0}]["s1 s0"] + f[{1, 1}]["s1 s1"]
```

Comment: it works perfectly. I modified Table[2,{numindices}] to Table[4,{numindices}] to let the indices go from 0 to 3